# Dashboard based on Todays Date - From a table

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a list of students with responsibilities and I would like to create a dashboard in Google Sheets with information about the current month.

As an example:

[image]

then in September 2020, I want the dashboard to show:

[image]

... and also update automatically to Jose and Gina once we are in Oct 2020

Here is the demo sheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/113ZAUJgbzgtjEGai9LkM22h-AEyaPymxUHMnu-RLYEw/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Thank you ... Added :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **EDIT**

As very correctly noticed in the [comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/145584/dashboard-based-on-todays-date-from-a-table#comment133095_145591), there is a hasty, common, still unforgivable **mistake in my original formula**.

### **The correct formula is**

```
=QUERY(Responsibilities!A2:C,"select B, C where month(A)="& month(A2)-1&"")
```

Please do notice that in order **to get the current month one needs to subtract 1 month**.

**WHY?**
Because **in a query formula**, when expressing months in numbers **`January` corresponds to `0`**
So the order of the months is:

```
  January       0  
  February      1  
  March         2  
  April         3  
  May           4  
  June          5  
  July          6  
  August        7  
  September     8  
  October       9  
  November     10  
  December     11
```

---

Original answer:

You would need 2 formulas in your dashboard sheet

**Formula 1**
You would first need to put today's date in a cell and refer to that cell to get the current month. That formula is:

```
=TODAY()
```

**Formula 2**
You can now use the following formula to get your results

```
=QUERY(Responsibilities!A2:C,"select B, C where month(A)="& month(A2)&"")
```

[image]

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`TODAY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092984)

Comment: Your solution is much better than mine. Thanks!

Comment: This was giving me the month ahead of today(), so I added an EDATE -1 and now its working properly for me ... =QUERY(Responsibilities!A2:C,"select B, C where month(A)="& month(EDATE(A2,-1))&"")

Comment: No need to complicate things using the `EDATE` function. Just use `month(A)="& month(A2)-1&"`.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it myself. Only took 4 hours :(

```
=Index(Responsibilities!$B$2:$B$7, MATCH(DATEVALUE(CONCATENATE(MONTH(today()),"/1/",Year(today()))),Responsibilities!A2:A7,0),1)
```

Comment: Great work. You can try my solution as well. I believe it is simpler.

Comment: Yours will auto fill with one formula, I will have more than these 2 columns so its nice, but if I dont want to have cells next to eachother, I will have to break up your solution as well.

Comment: Since it is a query you can rearrange the columns and even omit some according to your needs.